# NSSortComparator having no affect on NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, sorting, nsmutablearray

I am running the following code to sort my array in the order of ending soonest (nearest expiry_date to `[NSDate date]` (now).

However, whenever I run the comparator, it has no affect, at all on the array, and all objects retain their current positions. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
[self.questions sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary * question1, NSDictionary *question2) {

     NSDate* dateq1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[[question1 objectForKey:@"expiry_date"] floatValue]];
     NSDate * dateq2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[[question2 objectForKey:@"expiry_date"] floatValue]];

     NSComparisonResult result = [dateq1 compare:dateq2];

     NSLog(@"%@", result == NSOrderedAscending ? @"ASC" : result == NSOrderedDescending ? @"DESC" : @"SAME");

     return result;

}];
```

The NSLog() returns the following:

```
DESC
DESC
ASC
```

I have tried reversing the comparison to have `dateq2` in the place of `dateq1` and vice versa, but the array never changes, even though the returned values do.

Comment: Why do you think it didn't work? Just log the array before and after the sort - I think you will see its changed.

Comment: You are correct, I believe that theres a problem with the tableView reloading, rather than a problem with the sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is working to me (judging by your output), but maybe this is more succinct and therefore less error prone?

```
NSArray* unsorted;
NSSortDescriptor* descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"expiry_date" ascending: NO];
self.questions = [unsorted sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: @[ descriptor ] ];
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate way, but I have reason to believe that the tableView isn't updating, rather than the sorting process not working.

Answer (score 0):

Sort returns a new array; I don't think it changes the receiver.  I can't tell if you're doing an assignment or not.

Comment: sortUsingComparator (on NSMutableArray) does not return a new array. sortedArrayUsingComparator does.